# How to correctly insert references from jQuery, javascript and CSS in Bootstrap with ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, I'm working on a new personal project and I'm a beginner in Bootstrap.
What I'm trying to do for two days is; inserting dateTimePicker and number Incrementer using bootstrap techniques. And for doing this I searched a lot and tried many different tutorials, examples and none of those worked for me. I think that the problem should be the way of referencing the jquery libraries, javascripts and CSS. This is for the fact that I was trying to insert some glyphicons and they wouldn't appear to. So I'm asking how to correctly insert, arrange this libraries.

Here is what I have until now:

1) On my Site.Master in ASP.NET WebForms I have this references in the head Section:

```
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />



<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--
<link href="Content/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="Content/iThing.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    -->
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<!--
 <link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/common_o2.1-024e8f08a0bba6da7891dd4b6c39b7aa.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/p1/main-pretzel-f7ebfdaf120892e36656cf39bcc3addf.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/autocomplete-dd80b94ccaa2e37d6c20412621a9aeac.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

-->
<!--
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
    -->
```

2) In my Default.aspx page, where I'm trying to insert the datetimePicker and the other things and this page is a WebForm with Master I have this part for DateTimePicker in this occasion:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
```

3) The Result that I'm getting is the following:

doesn't work and doesn't show the calendar icon to

At the end of Default.aspx i have also included this scripts:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Somebody knows where I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you getting _any_ of your external js/css sheets to work?

Comment: Yes my only external css that works are the fontAwesome and googleWebFonts which i Have defined in this way in Site.Master page:


<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: It will be very helpful for me if you can show me an example of datepicker(not only, it could be something else to), what css, js and jquery librarys should i use and the way I should define them in my page.

Comment: I'll play around with this. However, at least for now, since your absolute url paths work, replace your file paths with their CDNs. So Bootstrap would be here: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/. Others can be found here: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker. Include their JS and CSS, see if that helps.

Comment: Ok now My calendar icon shows up which is a class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar", but the calendar doesn't show up when i Click on the icon ???

Comment: What i did was I added first the css: <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="search" />

and below i add the scripts: 

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Are all of your scripts being retrieved successfully? Check your network tab of your dev tools to confirm. I generally prefer using full paths when loading local scripts, like `<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js") %>"></script>`, especially when using master pages - that really helps when you have files in different directories.

Answer (score 1):

This guide created by Twinkle can help you set up your files properly: [Bootstrap 3.0 with ASP.NET](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-3-0-0-with-asp-net-web-forms)

As for a datepicker, I have used http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/jtf5cy2h/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="well">
  <input type="text" class="span2" value="02-16-2012" id="targetID" >
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#targetID').datepicker({
  format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
});
```

Comment: OK i Did the sam think as is here 
1) In the head section I added: 
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="search" />

Comment: THEN

2) Before the end of the BODY tag I added:
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script 
src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

Comment: AND

3) Inside the body I Added the code:

     
     <div class="well">
  <input type="text" class="span2" value="02-16-2012" id="targetID" >
</div>

<script>
$('#targetID').datepicker({
   format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
});
</script>

But Still doesn't work, it's soo frustrating

Comment: Move id="targetID" to your icon, instead. It should then call the calendar instead of the input field.

Comment: On which icon do you think??

Comment: I changed the place of the id and instead in the input field I added a span which has the calendar icon as a class and after that I inserted the targetID but I'm having the same issues, the Calendar doesn't show up, any suggestions will be very appreciated???